# Prove that if kv = 0 then either k = 0 or v = 0

Tags: vector-spaces

This should be simple, but I can't seem to get it. For vector space V over field F, prove that if fv = 0, then either f = 0 or v = 0 where $f \in F, v \in V$.

I see that if $ f \ne$ 0, then fv = 0 implies v = $f^{-1}$0 = 0, but when v $\ne 0$, how do I show that f = 0?

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement does not have *either* in it because *both* $f$ and $v$ can be zero:

> If $fv=0$, then $f=0$ or $v=0$.

Except for this detail, your proof is fine.

Indeed, you want to prove that $P \implies Q \lor R$.

Now $Q \lor R$ is equivalent to $\lnot Q \implies R$, which is what you have proved.

Comment: ok, i see, the statement is indeed proved, but I still feel like I should be able to prove that if v ≠ 0 and fv = 0, then f = 0 directly

Answer (score 1):

$k\cdot v=\vec{0}$ and $\vec{v}=\vec{0}\rightarrow k\cdot v=\vec{0}$. If $v\neq \vec{0}$, then:
$$k\cdot v=\vec{0}\rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \text{If}\hspace{2mm} k=0, \hspace{2mm} \text{it is proved.} \\
             \\ \text{If}\hspace{2mm} k\neq 0\rightarrow \exists k^{-1}\rightarrow k^{-1}(kv)=k^{-1}\cdot \vec{0}\rightarrow (*) 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
$(*)(k^{-1}k)v=\vec{0}\rightarrow 1\cdot v=\vec{0}\rightarrow v=\vec{0}\hspace{2mm} (\text{and we have assumed that}\hspace{2mm} v\neq \vec{0})\rightarrow k=0$